# Systemd dropping service start options

Tags: ubuntu, service, systemd, linux-mint, init.d

Why is systemd dropping options when using 'service start' ?

Man page of 'service' defines the service command as :

> **service** SCRIPT COMMAND [OPTIONS]

and states

> **service** passes COMMAND and OPTIONS to the init script unmodified.

Now take this init script for some service named "foo" :

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
        start)
                echo $2 >> output
        ;;
        someaction)          
                echo $2 >> output
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

On a system using systemd, after daemon-reload, `service foo start bar` writes nothing in output file while `service foo someaction bar` writes "bar" as expected. (Tested on Ubuntu 16.04)

On a system without systemd, both commands write "bar" as expected. (Tested on Mint 17.1)

I would bet stop command does the same.

Why are options dropped when start is called and not other "custom" commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `service` command was designed for SysV init scripts, not systemd. On `systemd` based systems, the `service` command may continue to exist as a shim to translated old syntax into new syntax. On Ubuntu 16.04, `/usr/sbin/service`is a bash script, so you you can read the source code and see where it has `is_systemd` conditional clauses. When looking at the `start` command on a systemd-based systems, you'll see this:

```
  systemctl $sctl_args ${ACTION} $unit
```

In other words, no additional args are passed through in this translation layer.

The replacement for `service` on `systemd`-based system is `systemctl`, with `systemctl start your-service-name` being used to start a service.

`systemd` does not support adding custom actions, but you can create custom `units` easily, so you could then do:

```
systemctl start myservice-someaction
```

Comment: Well that explains it. But then the service command does not follow its own specifications on systemd-systems. Is there a way to pass args with systemctl though?

Comment: You are right-- the `man service` docs mentions nothing about `systemd`, only `upstart`, which is not used on Ubuntu 16.04, either. No, you can't pass args through `systemctl start`, only create new units which then pass different options to underlying command when you start it. The design is to encourage increased consistency in how things are run in different contexts.

Comment: You could consider opening a bug report about the inaccurate `man` page for `service` in Ubuntu 16.04.